# UIPickerView is not working

Tags: ios, colors, tableview

I have a question about how to use UIPickerView. I have 2 VC which is connected between with a Push segue, in one I put an UIPickerView with 5 names of colours and in other I have a tableView, My question is, I want to change the colour on cell background when I select it from PickerView, down here I have the code how I tried to do. Please if anybody have any idea how to do this I will be very glad. Thanks in advance!!!!

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            self.color.text = @"Blue #0000FF";
            self.table.vi.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green: 0.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.color.text = @"Green #00FF00";
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green: 255.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.color.text = @"Orange #FF681F";
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/255.0f green:   140.0f/255.0f blue:31.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.color.text = @"Purple #FF00FF";
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:   0.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
        case 4:
            self.color.text = @"Red #FF0000";
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:   0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
        case 5:
            self.color.text = @"Yellow #FFFF00";
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:   255.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
}
```

And the code from tableView where I try to change the backgroundColor:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    self.vi = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [cell setBackgroundView:self.vi];
}
```

The problem is when I try to change the backgroundColor on same VC where the pickerView is, everything working, but when I try to pass it in another class is not working. 
Please Help!!!

Comment: How you sending the value to next class?

Comment: show us your code snippet , where you passing selected color to destination controller..

Comment: I understand that the way I'm trying to send the value to next class is wrong, can you show how right to send the value to next class??? When I change the background on same class, is working. I don't know how to change the background with colour that I selected from an UIPickerView from another class. Thank you!!!

Comment: I send the value in this way, but I understand that is wrong. I create a @property (strong, nonatomic) PlumbListTableViewController *table;  this is class where I want to show the background colour.  And in switch method I pass the colour in this way self.table.vi.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green: 0.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
            break;
And when I choose this colour, nothing is working....

Comment: Anyone can give me an advice please. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days I solved this problem. The best way to send values between 2 classes is via NSUserDefaults.